# Latex3 and \foreach: Do common operation over list of clist variables

Tags: luatex, foreach, latex3, loops, comma-separated-list

I am trying to learn LaTeX3. In writing one of my projects I faced a situation in which is usefull working with short comma-separated lists, testing whether they are empty, have only one item, etc ...

I have found solutions to all of that in LaTeX3. But I am having trouble finding a solution that allows to do common operation over comma-separated lists, for example clearing theyre contents. So I have tryed `\foreach` macro, but it doesnt seem to work.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_test_a
\clist_new:N \l_test_b

\clist_put_left:Nn \l_test_a {1,2}
\clist_put_left:Nn \l_test_b {3,4}

\newcommand{\writeLists}{%
 \l_test_a;  \l_test_b
}

\newcommand{\clearLists}{%
\foreach \n in {\l_test_a,\l_test_b}{%
\clist_clear:N \n}
}

\newcommand{\clearListsTheHardWay}{%
\clist_clear:N \l_test_a
\clist_clear:N \l_test_b
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\writeLists\par

\clearLists
\writeLists

\clearListsTheHardWay
\writeLists

\end{document}
```

What I expect to get is only one line of text, that is on the second invocation of `\writeLists` all of them to be empty. Even using global `\clist_gclear:N` doesnt give the result I was expecting, only `\clearListsTheHardWay` works, which I would like to avoid in general.

I suspect the issue is with `\foreach` not recognizing variables with LaTeX3 names. How can I fix this example to get expected result?

I am very much interested in solution that uses LaTeX3 functions, eventhough solution with lua is OK too, since I am runing LuaTeX anyway ...

Comment: foreach makes each iteration in a local group so is hard to use for any programming tasks but do you really need a pgf loop construct here, expl3 supplies far more powerful mapping and looping constructs

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I must have missed the constructs you are mentioning. Could you point me at which part of `expl3` you are referring to? I must have missed something obvious ...

Comment: Ah I realized what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Let's see... you can iterate over the control sequence names and use the `:c` parameter type instead of `:n`.

Comment: As for `foreach` it's better to not mix non-expl3 stuff and expl3 stuff and just use all expl3.

Comment: Alternatively loop over as usual, but you need to "dereference" (expand) the variable exactly once, with `:V` (or `:o`).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I should read more about function signatures, because I am a little confused from this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `\foreach`. For several reasons, the first of which being that it executes each item in the loop in a group.

The following code does the job: you define a sequence containing the lists you want to manage. With `\WriteLists` you “pretty print” the lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a list of lists
\seq_new:N \l_krulis_test_lists_seq

% the lists
\clist_new:N \l_krulis_test_a_clist
\clist_new:N \l_krulis_test_b_clist

% add them to the list of lists
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_krulis_test_lists_seq { \l_krulis_test_a_clist }
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_krulis_test_lists_seq { \l_krulis_test_b_clist }

% populate them
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_krulis_test_a_clist {1,2}
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_krulis_test_b_clist {3,4}

\cs_new:Nn \__krulis_test_write:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 1 } { ;~ }
  \clist_use:Nn #2 { ,~ }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeLists}{}
 {
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_krulis_test_lists_seq \__krulis_test_write:nn
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearLists}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_krulis_test_lists_seq
   {
    \clist_clear:N ##1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\writeLists

\clearLists

\writeLists

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this approach be used in general? That means, when I want to iterate over something in LaTeX3 I should create sequence from the individual elements and then map over them with either `seq_map_inline` if I need only the list itself, or with other function of that manner, or are there general limitations/use cases in which this approach doesnt work?

Comment: @TomášKruliš There are several mapping functions, but the idea is that, yes. I had a project to reimplement much of `\foreach` so to overcome its limitations, maybe it's time to get to work on it.